# CSS loading animation keeps displaying

Tags: jquery

I just created a CSS loading animation for my new website, and gave it a delay of 400ms but it keeps displaying? How can I get it disabled when the site is fully loaded in?

[image]

```js
/* ---------------------------------------------
     page  Prealoader JS
 --------------------------------------------- */


$(document).ready(function($) {
  'use strict';

  $(window).on('load', function() {
    $("#loading-center-page").fadeOut();
    $("#loading-page").delay(400).fadeOut("slow");
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Page Preloader HTML -->

<div id="loading-page">
  <div id="loading-center-page">
    <div id="loading-center-absolute">

      <div class="loader">O</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You're assigning an `onload` event to `window` *after* the page is fully loaded. Use *either* document/ready *or* the other one.

Comment: still doesn't seems to be working

Comment: Put your actual code in the question. Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/f6y25d3r/

Comment: https://codepen.io/bvethemlgpro/pen/vYNOzNe

Comment: Your pen doesn't properly include the necessary scripts. I fixed it: https://codepen.io/khrismuc/pen/MWawZXa

Answer (score 1):

Your window `load` event will not fire when it is inside the document `ready` also
you don't need to put window `load` event inside the document `ready` block just put in independently out side of the `ready` block like this

```js
  $(window).on('load', function() {
    $("#loading-center-page").fadeOut();
    $("#loading-page").delay(400).fadeOut("slow");
  });
```